# Tcsh run command if command was run

Tags: if-statement, command, tcsh

I'm not really familiar with TCSH

I would like run a `command2` if a `command1` was entered in the shell,  something like this:

```
if command1  then
    echo "Command succeeded"
    command2
else
    echo "Command failed"
fi
```

I tried this code but it doesn't work. Step two would be to read and print in a file a part some variable that command1 changed (making a kind of history only for some variables).

Comment: I disagree... I think trying things and seeing what happens is a good way to learn a language. Reading up is useful but definitely don't be afraid to try things and see what happens. You get insights and learn that way.

Answer (score 1):

You can use $? to get exit code from last command.

```
#!/bin/tcsh

# command below can fail or succeed
command1

if ( $? == 0 ) then
 command2
else
 echo "command1 failed"
endif
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, my situation is, if command1 is entered.
as you wrote the command1 will run anyway. 
Forgot to mentioned, I'd like have it in my cshrc.custom

Comment: OK, just to get it right. Do you want to run command_2 in case someone run command_1? Maybe alias will be a solution here? alias cmd 'command_1; command_2'